# Should the target variable be also normalised in SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, normalization, libsvm

I understand that normalization is an important preprocessing step for using SVMs, esp. before using non-linear kernels such as the radial basis functions. Should this normalization be applied to the target variable as well?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are going to use SVM to do classification. In classification, the target variable will be -1 or 1. Most importantly, the value $\{-1, 1\}$ has no meaning but representing the different classes in the target. So, I don't think normalization should be used to target data.

Comment: Ok. I did not mention that it is a regression problem. Is it same for regression as well?

Comment: @prashanth I think yes. On the one hand, the model will fit the pattern of target data. On the other hand, if you do the normalization for target data and train the model, then in predication, how can you find the real target data?